# How to change the same properties of different objects in one method?

Tags: c#

I have a method that performs the same function on different objects passed in:

```
public ??? DoThings(??? inputObject)
{
  //do things

  if(condition)
    inputObject.Status = "error";
}
```

Objects are of the following class:

```
public class BaseResponse<T>
{
  public string Status { get; set; }
  public T Data { get; set; }

  public static BaseResponse<T> FromJson(string data)
  {
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseResponse<T>>(data, JsonHelper.JsonSettings);
  }
}
```

At the end of the method I may need to change the object's `Status` to an error. How can this be achieved? I have tried to pass in `object inputObject`. but that of course doesn't work.

Comment: Like `public void DoThings<T>(List<BaseResponse<T>> manyInputObjects)`?

Comment: And likely you have a list of different T's and you want to invoke DoThings on each item, but unfortunately you don't know which item resolves to which T ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the method generic:

```
public void DoThings<T>(BaseResponse<T> inputObject)
{
    // do things

    if (condition) inputObject.Status = "error";
}
```

Then you can pass any `BaseResponse<T>` object:

```
var baseResponse = BaseResponse<SomeDataType>.FromJson(jsonString);
DoThings(baseResponse); // T can be inferred from baseResponse
```

Comment: Depends on the context of the call site whether or not T can be inferred.
If you deal with a list of objects of mixed types and for ease used an ArrayList or List<object> to collect them, T will not be so easily resolved.
It could be easier to add an non-generic `interface IStatus { string Status {get;set;} }` to BaseResponse. And type the formal parameter of DoThings by that interface. Assuming  you don't need the typing to BaseObject<T> or T in the code not shown....As usually - depends on the context...

Comment: @lidqy If `ArrayList` or `List<object>` are used, you wouldn't be able to call `DoThings` at all (without casting).

Comment: Yes but since he said "I tried to use 'object' but it didn't work" and also "I have a method that performs the same function on **different** **objects** **passed** **in**" there seems to be a problem to simply type DoThings param as 'BaseResponse<T>'.
Most of the time this happens when a generic collection is mixed and the T of each item is not known or its not so easy to get it compiled.

Comment: @lidqy OP tried `object` as the argument type, but `object` doesn't have a `Status` property.