# Change the same property of different objects without a common baseclass?

Tags: c#, object, generics

I found this thread: [How to change the same properties of different objects in one method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68348219/how-to-change-the-same-properties-of-different-objects-in-one-method)

But I have an additional requirement: I don't necessarily have a common baseclass for the objects:

I wish to change "Font" attribute on more objects with a function, but these objects are not originating from a common baseclass.

I'm however sure, that they all have "Font" attribute (or in case not let's drop a compile-time error). How am I supposed to do this with .NET Core7 in C#?

```
private void RescaleFont<?>(? control_with_font_attribute, double scale) {
  control_with_font_attribute.Font = ...;
```

Comment: `dynamic` .......

Comment: `RescaleFont( x => x.Font, scale )` would something like this fly for you?

Comment: @Fildor: I need to do manual adjustments to the original (x.Font) font, which would lead me to copy-paste my long codes N times for N objects, which I wish to avoid. :)

Comment: Don't all controls inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Contol` which has `Font` property?

Comment: @Daniel Fildors idea would not require that

Comment: if those are all your classes intruduce a interface with such property ...

Comment: @GuruStron But I think my Idea would not work, because Font is immutable, right?

Comment: We don't know if `Font` is from `System.Windows.Forms` ...

Comment: I implied that, correct. That was a little bit too fast.

Comment: @Fildor I thought about something else actually (see last option in my answer =)

Comment: Is setting a property the extent of your method? If so, then a method achieves nothing; just set the property directly.

Comment: I have to recalculate the font's size: `.Font = new Font(.Font.Name, .Font.Size * scale)`; and I wish to avoid writing this code N times.

Answer (score 1):

As @Selvin already implied in their comment:
Use the `dynamic` keyword.

Objects of type dynamic bypass static type checking and it is assumed that it supports the operation or called attribute.

If there are any errors you would get an exception at runtime. However at compiletime everything will seem "fine".

Your method would look like the following:

```
private void RescaleFont(dynamic control_with_font_attribute, double scale)
{
    control_with_font_attribute.Font = ...;
}
```

However please note that I'm not quite sure how safe it is to use or if it's acceptable designwise.

Comment: Yes, this seems working, however, can I somehow get build-error, in case "Font" attribute is not available?

Comment: @Daniel in short - no.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options:

- The best one - introduce a common base class or interface:

  ```cs
  public interface IHaveFont { FontType Font {get;set;}}

  private void RescaleFont<T>(T control_with_font_attribute, double scale) where T : IHaveFont
  {
     control_with_font_attribute.Font = ...;
  }
  // or 
  private void RescaleFont(IHaveFont control_with_font_attribute, double scale)
  {
     control_with_font_attribute.Font = ...;
  }
  ```
- Move the shared functionality to the common method and create bunch of overloads (you can generate them with source generators if needed):

  ```cs
  private void RescaleFont(SomeFontTypeA control, double scale) 
  {
        control.Font = Rescale(control.Font, scale));
  }

  private void RescaleFont(SomeFontTypeB control, double scale) 
  {
        control.Font = Rescale(control.Font, scale));
  }
  ```
- just use [source generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) to generate all required methods
- use [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) type (the other answer) - no type safety, runtime errors in case of property/field missing or type mismatch (can be mitigated with custom analyzer)
- use reflection - hence the `dynamic` but with ability to improve performance via "caching" it via dynamic compilation of [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62454454/2501279) for some inspiration)

  ```cs
  // generic so later can cache the reflection
  private void RescaleFont<T>(T control, double scale) where T : IHaveFont
  {
        var pi = typeof(T).GetProperty("Font");
        var newValue = pi.GetMethod.Invoke(control, null);
        pi.SetMethod.Invoke(control, new [] { newValue });
  }
  ```
- Use expression trees - a bit better type safety, but still possible to have runtime errors (if there is no setter for example) and need to duplicate the getter:

  ```cs
  private void RescaleFont<T>(T control, Expression<Func<T, FontType>> fontGetter, double scale) 
  {
     // analyze the fontGetter and use it to generate the setter
  }
  // and usage
  RescaleFont(someControl, x => x.Font, scale)
  ```

Comment: Ah, things go wrong. I just realized that on some "objects", I need to change "TitleFont" attribute instead of "Font".

Comment: @Daniel still several options from the list can be applied to the problem

Comment: The last one for example: just adapt to `RescaleFont(someControl, x => x.TitleFont, scale)` => https://dotnetfiddle.net/huuXkE

Answer (score 0):

## A. Write it twice

Write the method twice. There should be minimal duplication needed:

```
private void RescaleFont(Type1 ctrl, double scale) 
{
  ctrl.Font = GetFont(scale));
}

private void RescaleFont(Type2 ctrl, double scale) 
{
  ctrl.Font = GetFont(scale));
}
```

Please note that only setting the font is duplicated and `GetFont` is not duplicated, it's just called from two places.

## B. Add an interface

```
private void RescaleFont(IWithFont ctrl, double scale) 
{
  ctrl.Font = GetFont(scale));
}
```

## C. Control.Font Property

Are you sure that your controls aren't inheriting from the same base class, something like `System.Windows.Forms.Control`?

private void RescaleFont(System.Windows.Forms.Control ctrl, double scale)
{
ctrl.Font = GetFont(scale));
}

## D. Use reflection

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;



class A
{
    public Font Font { get; set; } = new Font("Arial", 4);
}

class B
{
    public Font Font { get; set; } = new Font("Arial", 3);
}

class C 
{

}


static void SetFont<T>(Font toSet, T target, Expression<Func<T, Font>> outExpr)
{
    var expr = (MemberExpression)outExpr.Body;
    var prop = (PropertyInfo)expr.Member;
    prop.SetValue(target, toSet, null);
}
```

Then:

```
var exampleFont = new Font("Arial", 11);

var a = new A();
SetFont(exampleFont, a, x => x.Font);


var b = new B();
SetFont(exampleFont, b, x => x.Font);


var c = new C();
SetFont(fontX, c, x => x.Font); // error CS1061: 'Program.C' does not contain a definition for 'Font'
```

Comment: Yes, duplication I wish to avoid, as I have more variations (3rd party lib).

Comment: IMHO a bit of duplication is significantly better than `dynamic`.

Comment: For B: I can't modify the 3rdparty library; For C: No they are not inheriting from Control.

Comment: @Daniel I added a solution with reflection (I still think a bit of duplication is the best option).